# Excel - Dynamic Name Range for Rows

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office, named-ranges

I have the width for the range I want correct, but am having issues dynamically adjusting the height for print preview. The number of rows for a weekly report adjusts weekly, so I'd like a way to create a Named Range that updates height automatically. 
Problem is, there are a number of blank rows mixed in there, and I want a way where I can find the very last value in Column A, even though there are blanks in between A1:A(whatever the last row is). Below is an example and my range formula, and if I attempt to print, the table is cut halfway through.

[image]

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,0,0,COUNT(Sheet1!$A:$A),12)
```

I attempted to put a white font in the blank column A cells, but have no luck. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use this formula to get what you need (use this formula under **Name Manager** with the name *print_area* scoped to the worksheet in question):
`=$A$1:INDEX($D$1:$D$1000,MATCH(9.99999999999999E+307,$A$1:$A$1000))`

- `$A$1` is what I call the anchor cell. This is the top left cell you want to print;
- `$D$1:$D$1000` is going to be the column to the far right that should "complete" your area (change `D` to the appropriate column and change `1000` to be a row that is farther down than your report would ever stretch); and
- The `MATCH` function is attempting to find the largest possible value in `$A$1:$A$1000`. *This only works for numerical data.* Be sure to use a column that'll have data in your last row (you stated that there may be blanks along the way).

**CAUTION:**

If you go this route, I *highly* recommend that you make the comment of the defined name something like: 

*Should equal: =$A$1:INDEX($D$1:$D$1000,MATCH(9.99999999999999E+307,$A$1:$A$1000))*. 

The reason being that if you go messing with the margins or print titles or something else, it'll likely reset the *print_area* and you'll have to start over.

Comment: Holy moley that worked! Thank you kind stranger! I hid the largest value on the last line, by making it in white font. So even if I added rows to the table, it would print everything in between.

Comment: I'm so glad it worked for you! The formula will work even if your very last value in the given column is something like **1**. The `MATCH` function is written in a way to find the last value in the given range (in this case, `$A$1:$A$1000`), even if it isn't the largest value in the whole column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to find the last row in column A. Since it searches from the bottom up, the blank rows above the last cell will not effect it.

```
LastRowColA = Worksheets(1).Columns(1).Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting a VBA solution? Your tag says VBA, but your formula is an Excel formula. If VBA, normally I just get the address of the ListObject (i.e. the Table) and extract the last row from it. Something like this:

```
With Sheet2

    .PageSetup.PrintArea = .Range("$A$1:" & .ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange.Cells(.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange.Cells.Count).Address).Address

End With
```

Comment: I have information outside of a table, so I wanted to avoid just printing the ListObject. The VBA comes in when I wanted to set the PrintArea of a Named Range, but I was having issues getting the last row to be viewed with the current formula I have.